# How to store to texture in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

You have a simple box, and an image shown inside.

You also have two textures, a red one, and a green one...

You initialize your used texture from the green texture...

Your window displays your unchanged used texture at first:

[image]

The shaded circle is around your mouse to display a portion of the texture.

When you press your mouse button, the shaded area changes to the red texture, as displayed below:

[image]

So far so good. However, I have searched quite a lot, but I can't find a way to store the result from the fragment shader to the displaying, used texture. The total operation would sum up to form a mix of the first and second textures.

Here's my relevant fragment shader:

```c
#version 120
uniform sampler2D red_texture, used_texture;
uniform bool isMouseClicked;
uniform float mousex, mousey;
uniform float radius; //the radius of the painting circle

void shadePixel(){ ... }

void main(){
   //calculate the distance from mouse origin
   float distance = sqrt(pow((gl_FragCoord.x - mousex), 2) + pow((gl_FragCoord.y - mousey), 2));

   if(distance<=radius && isMouseClicked){
    //used_texture <- red_tuxture
   }

   if(distance<=radius) shadePixel(); //make circle bound visible
   else gl_FragColor = texture2D(used_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```

I would like to later retrieve the texture to ram and save to disk as an image.

So, is there a way to manipulate the texture via the fragment shader?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a "render to texture".

1. render the image to a texture
2. save this texture to the disk
3. display in the window.

This is an EXAMPLE on how to prepare a texture to be rendered:

```
// create a texture "_textureId"
glGenTextures(1, &_textureId);
glBindTexture(TEXTURE_TARGET, _textureId);
glTexParameteri(TEXTURE_TARGET, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(TEXTURE_TARGET, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(TEXTURE_TARGET, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(TEXTURE_TARGET, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(TEXTURE_TARGET, 0, YOUR_INTERNAL_FORMAT, width, height, 0, YOUR_FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

// create the framebuffer "_frameBuffer" and associate to the texture above
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_frameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);
glBindTexture(TEXTURE_TARGET, _textureId);
glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, _textureId, 0);
GLenum drawBuffers[1] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 };
glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);
if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    // error...
}
```

The code above basically created a pair of texture + framebuffer, so you can render to the texture if you render to the framebuffer associated. In order to do that you can do something like this:

```
// do your normal render here... is goes to the image
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _frameBuffer);

// render whatever you want... glViewPort, glClear, glDrawArrays, etc...
// ...

// Switch back to the "default framebuffer" 0... it means, your window.
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

At this point you can again, render the texture `_textureId` to the window, as you wish... and optionally download the texture data to the GPU... this can be done with something like this:

```
glBindTexture(TEXTURE_TARGET, _textureId);
glGetTexImage(TEXTURE_TARGET, 0, YOUR_FORMAT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, _data);
```

Where `_data` is a buffer with size enough for you to keep your bitmap.

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to do this through the shader. Do you know if that is even possible?

Comment: @FrustratedSoul: you can do it with a compute shader and an `imageStore` on a new hardware. But I see no reason not to use the hardware provided blending through a render-to-texture as Wagner described.

Comment: "but I was hoping to do this through the shader:" Well, you compute your image (or whatever you want to compute) using the fragment shader and output it to a texture, I don't really see why you are not ok with this solution